# How do I get the value of a query string?

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

How do I access the value of a query string from a URL in a Magnolia CMS FreeMarker template? For example, given the following URL:

```
https://bobswebsite.com/about?campaign_id=90fsdfdsf80
```

How do I retrieve the value of the `campaign_id` query parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the parameter from the `ctx` object:

```
[#assign campaignParameter = ctx.campaign_id!]
```

If you need the whole query string, use the `getAggregationState` method:

```
[#assign wholeQueryStr = ctx.getAggregationState().getQueryString()!/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ctx.getParameter` templating function. For example:

```
[#assign queryString = ctx.getParameter("campaign_id")!]
```

*Source:* [Rendering context objects](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Rendering+context+objects#Renderingcontextobjects-ctx)